# Custom video player inside a Android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I have investigated some browsers in Android. They can play a video with their custom player when users click the html5 video tag item in a Webview. How to do this? More specifically, how to get the video url and how to trigger my custom player instead of VideoView created by Android system when users click the video tag?

Comment: What browsers have you seen that do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking support for the `<video>` tag, it would be impossible to do that without the help of additional JS libraries such as [Video.js](https://videojs.com). This is because the Android WebView depends on another web browser (e.g. Chrome) to render the content, hence the web browser is then responsible for providing the video player.

Of course, there are some alternatives, such as extracting the `<video>` source URLs and load it into a custom player. However, this may not work for all cases since some sites (including YouTube) prefer to play with the `<video>` DOM APIs instead of internal `<source>` tags to point the web browser/video player which content should be played next.