# Android webview video player

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to create simple web browser but faced with a problem! When I am loading a page with video, it starts playing with default video player. But, as I have seen in other web browsers, video starts playing with custom player. Can anyone tell me how did they implement a custom player into webview?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using webview?

Comment: Yes, a webview, it's a typo

Comment: same question here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275752/custom-video-player-inside-a-android-webview,
but with no answers.
could you look at https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but it has a lot of errors